# file not creating in android internal storage

Tags: android, android-studio

This is function for saving images. I am trying to save the image name (from gallery) to a file (preferably csv file). but the android is not creating the file. need help in creating the file in android internal storage.

public void saveImage(String imagePath){

```
    String[] arrOfStr = imagePath.split("/");             //splitting full image path by / to only get the image name e.g 00001.jpg
    String imageName = null;

    for (String a : arrOfStr)
        imageName = a;                             // imageName only contains the imageName i.e 00001.jpg
    

    String filename = "test_ids.txt";

    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, filename);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(imageName);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

                }

                break;
            case 1:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    if (selectedImage != null) {
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                            saveImage(picturePath);                     // a function to save images
                            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                            cursor.close();

                        }
                    }

                }
                break;
```

Comment: On which android version you are testing it?

Comment: `root.mkdirs();` The directory is not even created but you are unaware as you are not checking the return value. If false you should stop and not try to create a file.